# React child component seems not to be rendered when parent state is updated?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I have a (probably stupid) question about the workflow in react which I obviously did not yet fully understand.

I have a parent component which fetches data from the server through an ajax call. One of the return values is a boolean which is passed to the child component as a property. The child component however again fetches data from the server (ajax) according to the property value. Somehow the parent component does it's changes accordingly but the child does not re-render? What am I doing wrong?

Parent component:

```
var L5fmModal = React.createClass({

        getInitialState : function() {
            return {
                initRunSwitch : false,
                data : []
            };
        },

        componentDidMount: function() {
            this.loadItems('L5fm/setState', null);
        },

        loadItems : function(url, modalState) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                data: {modalState : JSON.stringify(modalState)},
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    this.setState({data: data, initRunSwitch: true});
                    console.log(this.state.data);
                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                    console.error(url, status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this)
            });
        },

        changeListView : function() {
            if (this.state.data.listView) {
                var newData = update(this.state.data, { listView: { $set: false }  });
            }
            else {
                var newData = update(this.state.data, { listView: { $set: true } });
            }
            this.loadItems('L5fm/setState',newData);
        },

        changeDirectory : function() {
            if (this.state.data.dirState.private) {
                var newData = update(this.state.data, {dirState : { private: { $set: false } } });
            }
            else {
                var newData = update(this.state.data, {dirState : { private: { $set: true } } });
            }
            this.loadItems('L5fm/setState',newData);
        },


        render: function() {

            if (this.state.initRunSwitch) {
                if(this.state.data.dirState.private) {
                    var browseIcon = "glyphicon-folder-open";
                    var browseText = "browse all files";
                }
                else {
                    console.log('undefined here');
                    var browseIcon = "glyphicon-briefcase";
                    var browseText = "browse private files";
                }

                if (this.state.data.listView) {
                    var listIcon = "glyphicon-picture";
                    var listText = "image View";
                }
                else {
                    var listIcon = "glyphicon-list";
                    var listText = "list View";
                }
            }

            return(

                <Modal {...this.props} bsSize="large" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg">
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <div className="header-button-group">
                            <L5fmHeaderButton buttonIcon="glyphicon-cloud-upload" buttonText="upload" />
                            <L5fmHeaderButton onClick={this.changeListView} buttonIcon={listIcon} buttonText={listText} />
                            <L5fmHeaderButton onClick={this.changeDirectory} buttonIcon={browseIcon} buttonText={browseText} />
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    {this.state.initRunSwitch ? <L5fmModalBody dirState={this.state.data.dirState} listView={this.state.data.listView} />:null}
                </Modal>
            );
        }

    });
```

Child component ():

```
var L5fmModalBody = React.createClass({

        getInitialState : function() {
            return {
                files : []
            };
        },

        componentDidMount: function() {
            this.loadFiles('L5fm/setModalBodyState', this.props.dirState);
        },

        loadFiles : function(url, dirState) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                data: {dirState : JSON.stringify(dirState)},
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    this.setState({files: data});
                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                    console.error(url, status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this)
            });
        },

        render: function() {

            var object = this.state.files;

            return(
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Grid fluid={true}>
                        <Row>
                            {this.props.listView ? <L5fmModalBodyListView fileObject={object} /> : <L5fmModalBodyImageView fileObject={object} />}
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </Modal.Body>
            );
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is run only on the initial render ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)). You should react to subsequent *prop* changes inside `componentWillReceiveProps`.